# Can you change the location of azure-pipelines.yaml in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to configure an Azure DevOps pipeline to look for the `azure-pipelines.yaml` file in a custom location?

We're using a mono-repo source control architecture for our current work with different packages held under `packages/<package-name>` and only one of them needs an Azure DevOps pipeline, so ideally we'd like to have the YAML configuration stored with the package rather than at the root of the repo, but I can't find any options for this in the DevOps portal. This is definitely configurable in other similar services like AWS CodeBuild.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

yes you can do that, when creating the build use old UI wizard, if you already have a build in place, you can open its settings>variables (or triggers) and then navigate to the YAML section and under `YAML file path` you can change it

click the `...` on the build edit page next to the `Run` button:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

The UI has changed a bit so it's now under the **Settings** sub menu of the pipeline:

[image: Pipeline settings]

[image]

*This solution also works for the cases when you simply want to rename
 the YAML file to whatever you believe is more appropriate rather than
 default **azure-pipelines.yml**. For instance, you might have several
 builds in the same repo: build_asp_net.yml, build_docker_image.yml,
 etc.*

Answer (score 7):

The YAML file from a subfolder may be chosen on the third step of pipeline creation wizard.

[image]

Comment: anyway we can change the location to another repository ? What i mean by this is the source code is in repository A and yaml file is in repository B. The reason why i need this is because repository A is read only and i have no control on it.

Comment: @Garfield did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @Simon : Yes , [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61097240/source-code-and-yaml-file-in-a-different-git-repo/61115326?noredirect=1#comment108387633_61115326)

Answer (score 2):

While creating a pipeline just click on default file name (azure-pipelines.yaml) and this will make it a text editable and rename location/folder path according to your need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can! But only if you configure your build correctly in the first place and click 'use classic editor', then select a YAML project. Any projects that have been configured via the newer wizard expect the YAML file in the root and can't be changed.

[This blog post](https://sethreid.co.nz/using-multiple-yaml-build-definitions-azure-devops/) describes the process, though the UI has changed slightly since it was written.

Comment: no, that is wrong, read my answer. you can change those for newer pipelines as well

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Navigate to project / pipelines / YAML section