# Source Code and YAML file in a different Git Repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

A GitHub repository A provides read only access and I am trying to build a Azure DevOps pipeline on top of this.

Since the YAML file needs to be written into the same repository, I get an error while trying to save to a read-only location, which is expected. I know the location of the YAML file can be changed inside the git repo, but what i am trying to implement is saving the YAML file into repo B which builds code from repo A.

The YAML file should do a build of repo A.

I couldn't find any documentation on this and feel this might not be possible, but is that mentioned anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what i am trying to implement is save YAML file into repo B which
>   builds code from Repo A

For this issue , you can checkout repo A in the yaml file stored in repoB.

Pipelines often rely on multiple repositories. You can have different repositories with source, tools, scripts, or other items that you need to build your code. By using multiple `checkout` steps in your pipeline, you can fetch and check out other repositories in addition to the one you use to store your YAML pipeline.

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: GitHubRepoA # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
```

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-declared-using-a-repository-resource) you can refer to.

Comment: Works like a charm . Thanks for the help. But i was wondering why doesn't the azure devops have these options through UI.

Comment: @Garfield I think this is because yaml will be the main recommended way in the future.If this answer is helpful to you , would you please [mark it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Could you please an example of what should be provided as endpoint & name?